# Url Validation using Restforce

Tags: auth

I have my app in ruby on rails. I am using restforce for all communication with Salesforce.

After authentication we save user url and access token. But there were some cases where customers changed their salesforce domain urls and when restforce tried to fetch data, system crashed with error invalid domain.

Is there anywhere I can ping salesforce using restforce or get notification when url is changed.
In my case I have to ask user to re-sync get updated info.

Comment: Have you [created an issue](https://github.com/restforce/restforce/issues) for the restforce developer?

Comment: No I will create one